# Date Time and Conversion Functions not available in MS Access 365 at Table Design Time

Tags: date, ms-access, type-conversion

I'm trying to simply convert a text field into a datetime value in MS Access 365.  This should be simple.  However I don't seem to have access to functions like Date(), DateValue().

I want something where I can just pass some text in and it converts to a datetime type.  My data looks like this:
[image]

I used the formula:  I used this formula to get this: Left$([DateText],InStr(1,[DateText]," - "))
to remove the time from the DateText field.

Now I want to add a new field which is a date/time type using the data in the DateTextWithTimeRemoved field.

The table design view (also showing the conversion functions available) is like this:
[image]

And the date functions are these:
[image]

And so, from years ago I remember using functions like CDate() or Date() or DateValue() or what have you, but they're just not there.  Do I have to install something to get these functions?

Comment: They are not available to Calculated field type in table design. Do calcs in query or textbox.

Comment: @June27.  Ah.  Man I wonder where this is spelled out?  That seems to be the answer though.  If you'd like to post it as an answer, I'll mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: Why is your date/time value in a text field?

Comment: I have imported the data from Excel and it's all text.  I'm trying to convert that field that contains date and time info into a date/time type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to keep the same Table fields shown in your question:

1. Make a backup of your current table.
2. Change the Data Type of the `DateThatIsAnActualDate` field to Date/Time and `DateTextWithTimeRemoved` to Short Text.
3. Create an an Update Query. (Create -> Query Design -> select Update under Query Type.)
4. Add your Table (members)

   ```
    Field: DateTextWithTimeRemoved
    Table: members
    Update To:
   ```

`Left([DateText],InStr(1,[DateText]," -"))`

*next column*

```
    Field: DateThatIsAnActualDate
    Table: members
    Update To:
```

`Format(DateValue(Left([DateText],(InStr(1,[DateText]," -")))),"dd/mm/yyyy")`

5. Click Run !
6. Click Yes to confirm.
7. All done. Check the records in the members table.

Answer (score 0):

First, forget about the calculated fields. Use queries, that's what they are for. Tables are for data.

Second, the Expression Builder is hopeless. I have never found it useful.

Next, all you need for an easy conversion to true date values, is to remove the dash.

```vb
TextDate = "10 Dec 2020 - 16:52"

? Replace(TextDate, "-", "")
10 Dec 2020  16:52
```

This can be converted like this:

```vb
' Date only:
? DateValue(Replace(TextDate, "-", ""))
2020-12-10

' Date and time:
? CDate(Replace(TextDate, "-", ""))
2020-12-10 16:52
```

Now, your query could look this this:

```sql
Select
    ID,
    Username,
    DateValue(Replace(TextDate, "-", "")) As TrueDate,
    CDate(Replace(TextDate, "-", "")) As TrueDateTime
From
    Members
```

Note, that date/time values carry no format. Apply this for display only, so adjust the Format property where needed (the forms/reports where you view the data), if the default format (that of your Windows settings) doesn't fit.

```
Format: dd/mm/yyyy
```

The default is:

```
Format: Short Date
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer.  It looks like you're using a REPL or command line - you show the question mark and then commands.  Where/how are you doing this please?  The other guy who answered is new to StackOverflow and his answer is correct.  It's not quite as good as yours, but he's new and so I want to reward him.  I hope you'll understand.

Comment: The Immediate Window of VBA editor.

Comment: Jeremy's answer is the better one if your goal is to change data in the table and not just calculate in query.

Comment: It is never a better option to store date or time as text.